# Javascript & jquery return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, return

I've been staring at the following problem for 3 hours now. I would like to start the whole code from the beginning after finishing the 'newLevel'-function at the bottom of the code. I've been trying to wrap the code inside of if() and while() statements but just can't get it to work.

Shortly the problem is that newLevel()-function can't send the new value of variable level to the beginning of the code. How could I do this?

Thank you for the downvotes!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var level = 1;

if(level == 1)
{random variables}

if(level == 2)
{random variables}

if(level == 3)
{random variables}


$('#check').click(function(){ // if we click 'Check correct answer button

    if(givenAnswer == correctAnswer)
    {
        $('#raisingCrystals').animate({ 
            'marginTop' : "-=51%", 
            'opacity' : '0.0'
            },2000, function(){
                $('#crystalsH3 > h3').html('+3'); 
                $('#crystalsH3 > h3').css('color','#0D5C94'); 
                $('#crystalsH3').animate({
                    'font-size' : "10vw"
                    },2000, function(){
                            $('#totalPoint > h3').html(totalPoints);
                            $('#speak4 > p').css('font-size','1.7vw');
                            $('#speak4 > p').html('Blaa blaa...');
                            $('#check > h2').html('---Next assesment---');

            // let's do a function that check, if the '---Next assesment---'-button is clicked

                    $('#check > h2').click(function newLevel(){
                            level++;
                        });     
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You'd have better to provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue and explain better your expected behaviour. Firstly, you should check `level` inside click handler i guess but i'm not sure as your code doesn't make much sense actually without knowing what are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part of your code with this:

```
$('#check > h2').click(function () {
    level++;
});
```